# Find the max in a list of lists of type Numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell and am trying to find the max value in a list of lists that contain type Numbers. Numbers is defined as:

```
data Numbers = StrNumber String | IntNumber Int
                deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

I already have a function that finds the max int value in a list of lists of type int.

```
nested_max :: [[Int]] -> Int
nested_max [] = minBound::Int
nested_max list = maxL (map maxL list)
     where
          maxL xs = foldr gt (minBound::Int) xs
          gt x y = if x < y then y else x
```

And can use getInt to convert Numbers to ints.

```
getInt x = read x::Int
```

I've been trying to map getInt to every value in the list being passed in and then applying nested_max on that list, but keep getting errors.
This is what I've been trying:

```
getInt x = read x::Int
to_int :: [[Numbers]] -> [[Int]]
to_int list = map (\x-> getInt x) list
```

An example of what the program should do is...
**Input:** find_max_number [[StrNumber "9",IntNumber 2,IntNumber 8],[StrNumber "4",IntNumber 5],[IntNumber 6,StrNumber "7"],[],[StrNumber "8"]]
**Output:** 9

Comment: Show us the wrong thing you tried and the error message you get, please.

Comment: I added what I have been trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is my attempt:

```hs
data Numbers
  = StrNumber String
  | IntNumber Int

nestedMax :: [[Numbers]] -> Int
nestedMax = maximum . map toInt . concat
  where toInt (StrNumber x) = read x
        toInt (IntNumber x) = x

main = do
  print $ nestedMax [[StrNumber "9",IntNumber 2,IntNumber 8],[StrNumber "4",IntNumber 5],[IntNumber 6,StrNumber "7"],[],[StrNumber "8"]] -- 9
```

I hope the code is straightforward...